# what is the difference between polyserve and polymer serve?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to know that what is the difference between two commands polyserve and polymer serve in polymer. Are they work as same command or their function is different.[image: polyserve]

[image: polymerserve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polymer is a CLI that uses Polyserve internally to create HTTP server accoding to a discussion on [Polyserve repository](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polyserve/issues/100) site.

See [Relationship to Polymer CLI](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-build#relationship-to-polymer-cli).